# Where are the backlight connectors in my Samsung notebook?

Tags: laptop, backlight

With a Samsung Q210, 12.1" I have backlight issues.

It was no surprise due to the intensity of its use, that after about 6 months and 1 week, the **screen backlight** started to fail intermittently. I want to have a closer look at the solder of the backlight-inverter, probably there are some bad connections.

Where can I find this part? Below the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't personally taken this model of laptop apart but typically laptop inverter boards are located on the bottom portion of the screen.

In order to gain access to this piece you generally need to remove a series of screws and snap ins that hold the plastic covering over the screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: good day dear jmreicha - many  thanks for the quick reply - great to hear from you. And your explanations are just brilliant! Keep up your superb work! You rock! GREETINGS   - you saved my day!

Comment: @zero You can thank people by voting on their answers and marking them as accepted.